# What is the best way to word response to customer asking for subscription renewal discount?

Tags: business-writing, email

Can I ask this type of question here? Not sure if I'm in the right place. I apologize if this is off topic here.

I started a subscription service a year ago. I offer 1 year and lifetime subscriptions. If you choose to subscribe for a year, at the time of renewal, you can renew for another year or you can go with lifetime. But there is no discount.

Customer is demanding a renewal discount equal to what they paid for the last year applied to the lifetime subscription. I'm hesitant to do so.

Kinda like the Web Hosting industry, if you choose the 3 year plan you get a steeper discount. But you don't get to choose the year first and then apply that to a three year discounted plan at renewal time.

What I am here asking, is how can I explain this in my response so that it makes sense without rambling on and angering a customer?

Thank you.

Comment: Not a writing advice, but you can invent a 2-3 year subscription plan and offer _some_ discount. Major companies' customer service often offer small discounts or other tchotchkes to keep existing customers happy.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not intend to offer a discount then write something like this.  You may need to change some of it (for example, I've assumed your price structure is explained on your website, that ought to be but may not be true), and you may want to adjust it slightly to suit your vocabulary (maybe you prefer 'I' to 'we' that kind of thing), local spelling, *etc* ...

> Dear Customer,
>
> I'm sorry but we are not able to offer you the discount you have asked
> for.  Our pricing model is clearly explained on the website.
>
> We have many customers who are entirely satisfied with the quality of the services we provide and we are confident that the services are good value, especially the lifetime subscription.
>
> Yours ...

There, no waffle and (I think) entirely clear and sensible.  It is short and to the point and leaves the customer in no doubt about your position.  You might want to 'punch up' the sales pitch in the second paragraph of the letter.  You might even be able to make reference to the value the customer got out of the service in the first year.

Of course you're not really sorry at all, but expressing it that way softens the blow.

You are not explaining your pricing policy.  Any explanation you offer invites a further response from the customer and then you are into a negotiation, which will only serve to waste your time and risks eventually angering your customer.